# Relative URL path in form action not working

Tags: html

I'm a making a form but clicking on that form's submit button doesn't take me to the right path.

```
<form action="delete" method="post">
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

It should take me to `http://localhost:5000/<id>/delete`
(In place of  will be the user ID)

But it takes me to `http://localhost:5000/delete`

And `http://localhost:5000/<id>/delete` is a webpage not a file. Which means that this web site is not static, it's dynamic.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It will lead you to http://localhost:5000/id/delete only if your current URL is http://localhost:5000/id/. Try to put this in action: "/id/delete"

Comment: @Moebius The `id` in URL is actually a placeholder for user ID. I thought it's not relative to the question so I didn't add it before but now I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to extract the ID from the URL and then set that ID into your form action like:

follow this stackoverflow question to extract ID from url [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
<form action="/<id>/delete" method="post">
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Assuming your `delete` is a file and it is in the same directory (`id/`) as your current html file.

A little thing about paths:

- `pathname` is absolute. This means it will search in the root directory for pathname. (in this case the root folder of your webapp)
- `./pathname` is relative. The `.` means the current directory (aka the directory your file (e.g. `index.html`) is in).
- `../pathname` is also relative. The `..` means one folder over the current folder you are in.

**Example:**

```
rootFolder/
  test.html
  anotherFolder/
    otherFile.html
  folder/
    index.html
    delete.html
```

Now assuming you are in `folder/`

- `test.html` -> Valid
- `./test.html` -> Does not exist since `.` == `rootFolder/folder/`
- `../anotherFolder/otherFile.html` -> Valid, since `..` goes one folder up (from `folder/` to `rootFolder`) and then enters `anotherFolder/otherFile.html`

The exact same principles also apply when you open your terminal and `cd` (change directory) around. You can try out that the path works there first.

To answer your question, it should be: `action="./delete"` you are using an absolute path right now.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to specify in my question that `delete` is a page and not a file. I'll edit my question now.